# Why does this simple select by primary key show such intensive CPU usage?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have advanced performance metrics enabled for my `m6g.xlarge` MySQL instance in RDS.  I'm noticing that the during CPU spikes (which are expected given our app), that it seems a simple query is occupying the most CPU.

The blue query is:

```
SELECT * FROM `job_batches` WHERE `id` = "91b0f7a8-0693-4cb4-8647-e7509318fbbc" LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE
```

[image]

I did an explain thinking that might shed some light on it, but the explain looks fine/efficient to me.

[image]

**Am I correct in my understanding that this simple query is what's driving a good amount of our CPU usage?**.  From a query volume perspective, I would expect to see the same number of `SELECT * FROM job_batches...` queries as I would say the orange `SELECT * FROM channel_subscription`.  This makes the blue stand out to me as an area of potential optimization.

The table's architecture is:

```
CREATE TABLE `job_batches` (
  `id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `total_jobs` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pending_jobs` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `failed_jobs` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `failed_job_ids` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `options` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `cancelled_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `finished_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Is it using lots of CPU or do you just have active sessions calling that SQL at any one point that are potentially waiting for the `for update` lock?

Comment: That's a great question!  The framework we use for our app is appending the `FOR UPDATE`, so it'll take some digging for me to figure out where it's coming from.

Comment: I do not expect a primary key lookup of a single row to take a lot of CPU, nor lock-waits by other sessions waiting for that locked row. I'm guessing it's a coincidence that there was high CPU load. Try to repeat the query and see if it happens again. If there is high CPU load, observe `SHOW PROCESSLIST` and see if there are a lot of queries running, and what they're doing.

Comment: SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; may provide additional helpful information. Could you post TEXT results of SHOW INDEX FROM job_batches;

Comment: The explain results indicate the primary key is KEYLEN of 1022. Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE job_batches; so we can see the current structure of the table column for column named id.  This url in Step 4 may have helpful information related to using utf8mb4 stored data.  https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Answer (score 0):

A possible explanation:

- The table is nearly as big as `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.
- The Could did some sort of maintenance just before that spike, hence the buffer_pool (cache) was lost.
- UUIDs are terribly inefficient because of how random they are.
- Each `SELECT` (during the spike) found the desired row to not be cached, so it had to read from disk.  (Was there also a spike in I/O?)

If the table is growing is size, the problem will become noticeably worse when the table becomes bigger than the buffer_pool.